# Why is continuity Required for Existence and uniqueness theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why is continuity Required for Existence and uniqueness theorem

Recently i am studying "Existence and uniqueness theorem" first order differential
equation

ie my IVP is $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y), y(x_0)=y_0$

and here is $f(x,y) $ is continuity in both $x,y$ and so from this we studied "Uniqueness" of the second order by converting system of equation and hence we studied  "Uniqueness"  of $n^{th}$ order differential

and **my first question is why need continuous always what if i remove continuity**

and for non-homogeneous differential equation

id $y''+ay'+by=f(x)$

**my second question is for what condition of $f(x)$ we can apply Uniqueness theorem**

I am sorry i dont know this is good question or not but i got this questions in my mind

Comment: Regarding your second question, if $a$ and $b$ are constants then the local (Lebesgue) integrability of the function $f$ is sufficient for both existence and uniqueness of the solution of an IVP, see the bottom of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_existence_theorem#Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up Peano's existence theorem and the Picard-Lindelof theorem. You need "for all $x$, the function $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is Lipschitz continuous" to get uniqueness. There's a counterexample at the bottom of the relevant [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Other_existence_theorems).